# Dynamical pressed image for icon in android

Tags: android

I have an icon which has different images on different run and for each image on the icon there is another image corresponding to that image which is the images which has to be shown when it is pressed.
i.e. I want to change the pressed image of an icon programatically. IS there any way to do that. Help please.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

img.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/img_selected" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/img_selected" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/img_disabled" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_selected" />
</selector>
```

and set background this xml for imageview

Comment: Can you please explain how to set this xml as background for the ImageButton.. ALso where to save this xml, IS it in the drawable folder. I tried this but giving error.. icon1.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.img);

Comment: can we dynamically specify an xml as background for a ImageButton.

Comment: save this xml in drawable folder..and set android:background="@drawable/img" for ImageView in xml...

Comment: @ CapDroid : I want to dynamically change the xml. Is it possible.

Comment: @James it will automatically change image when you press on image, so why you want it at dynamically.?

Comment: Because everytime I run I want to have a new XML as background..No Problem I got it......icon1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img);